# Programmatically adding items to usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My MainWindow.xaml get it´s datacontext from MyClass.cs and it´s view from usercontrol  in MyView.xaml as below

```
  <Window.DataContext>
     <ViewModel:MyClass/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <View:MyView/>
```

The usercontrol has grid, stackpanel and a button as below

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Height="300" Width="502">
  <StackPanel x:Name="MainStackPanel" Height="200" Width="400"/>
  <Button x:Name="NewButton" Command="{Binding CommandAddNewButton}" Content="new item" Height="25" Width="55" Margin="224,177,223,98"/>
</Grid>
```

From MyClass I try to add button and textbox to the stackpanel programatically by pressing the "new item" button as below

```
public ICommand CommandAddNewButton
{ get { return new MyCommand(AddNewButton); } }

private void AddNewButton()
{
  var newButton = new Button
  { 
    Name = "Button" + _itemNbr,
    Content = "-",
    FontSize = 10,
    Height = 20,
    Width = 15,
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige),
    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10)
  };

  var newTextBox = new TextBox
  {
    Name = "TextBox" + _itemNbr, 
    Height = 20, 
    Width = 70, 
    FontSize = 10, 
    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
    VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
  };

  MainStackPanel.Children.Add(newButton);
  MainStackPanel.Children.Add(newTextBox);
}
```

A new button and textboxe are created after button press but they do not displayed. How can I fix it? All help are appreciated.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.View.MyView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-      compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModel"
         xmlns:View="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.View">

 <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Height="300" Width="502">
   <StackPanel x:Name="MainStackPanel" Height="200" Width="400"/>
   <Button x:Name="NewButton" Command="{Binding CommandAddNewButton}"  Content="new item" Height="25" Width="55" Margin="224,177,223,98"/>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: how do you access MainStackPanel in Myclass?

Comment: Directly like this MainStackPanel.Children.Add(newButton); as it is a public in xaml and have ofc public class MyClass : MyView in MyClass.cs so the stackpanel is accessible.

Comment: You can access `StackPanel` physical instance (which is "public in xaml") only from xaml code-behind, unless you explicitly pass it to `MyClass` in code.

Comment: Yes you totally right I ment becuse I have public class MyClass : MyView in MyClass.cs

Comment: The accessing is not the problem I Think anyway because as I wrote new button and textboxe are created after button press but they do not displayed.

Comment: So you have `MyView` class which is your custom `UserControl`, and you derive your `MyClass` (using as view-model) from that user control? In that case I believe your `MainStackPanel` variable in `MyClass` has nothing common with actual `StackPanel` that displaying during runtime, hence your changes over `MainStackPanel` in `MyClass` has no affect.

Comment: Ty all, of course I just realized that you good folks are pointed out for me that I accessed to a different instance of the stackpanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are inheriting your View(Myview) to your viewmodel(Myclass). so that you are accessing a different instance of stackpanel. One method you can do is pass stackpanel as a paramater to the view model .

In Xaml:

```
 <Button x:Name="NewButton" Command="{Binding CommandAddNewButton}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainStackPanel}"  Content="new item" Height="25" Width="55" Margin="224,177,223,98"/>
```

In ViewModel:

```
private void AddNewButton(object obj)
{
    var MainStackPanel= obj as StackPanel;
}
```

Comment: It was a perfect suggestion. Work like a charm. Ty :)